# Get a PHPActiveRecord result as simple array, not array of objects

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpactiverecord

**I would like to have a simple a method, that can give back PHP Activerecord results as simple/associative arrays, not an array of ActiveRecord Objects.**

In Ruby I believe this is done perhaps with `.map()` method. (I am not a Ruby guy...)

What I want is a simple method call, like `toArray()` in Zend_DB_Table, not a foreach, or something like that, but I can't seem to find it in their [docs](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/docs/index/main).

In PHP ActiveRecord getting a result is really easy:

```
$settings = SystemSettings::all();
```

But it gives back something like this:

```
[0] => SystemSettings Object
    (
        [errors] => 
        [attributes:ActiveRecord\Model:private] => Array
            (
                [param] => author
                [value] => Hawle
            )

        [__dirty:ActiveRecord\Model:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [__readonly:ActiveRecord\Model:private] => 
        [__relationships:ActiveRecord\Model:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [__new_record:ActiveRecord\Model:private] => 
    )

[1] => SystemSettings Object
    (
        [errors] => 
        [attributes:ActiveRecord\Model:private] => Array
            (
                [param] => base_url
                [value] => example.com
            )

        [__dirty:ActiveRecord\Model:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [__readonly:ActiveRecord\Model:private] => 
        [__relationships:ActiveRecord\Model:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [__new_record:ActiveRecord\Model:private] => 
    )
```

While this is really great in many cases, here, I would just like to have a simple array, like this:

```
Array
    (
        [author] => Hawle
        [base_url] => example.com
    )
```

Comment: I have also tried this, but it is not a real solution:
$result = SystemSettings::all();
$json_encoded = $result->to_json();
$decoded = json_decode($json_encoded);

Comment: if all you want are arrays, why are you using an activerecord class in the first place?

Comment: I would like to use the activerecord class as it is for the most cases, but in special cases like that, I would just like to have a simple method. I was wondering if there was a method already like for example ->to_json() serialization. I can write my own functions for it, but was wondering if you guys know of any method that exists, maybe undocumented, etc.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: @dqhendricks - I am sorry, but I believe you are not understanding my question. I am NOT looking for a PHP alternative, but a phpactiverecord method [www.phpactiverecord.org](http://http://www.phpactiverecord.org). ->to_json is like that.

Comment: i'm not sure that you are understanding. add the method to phpactiverecord yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a similar issue hopefully this can help someone else who stumbles on it. Obviously, this is specific to phpactiverecord.org.

In /lib/Model.php I added the following function:

```
public function to_array(array $options=array())
{
    return $this->serialize('array', $options);
}
```

In /lib/Serialization.php I added the following class

```
class arraySerializer extends Serialization
{
    public static $include_root = false;

    public function to_s()
    {
        return self::$include_root ? array(strtolower(get_class($this->model)) => $this->to_a()) : $this->to_a();
    }


}
```

I can then call ->to_array() and get an array back.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanx, although in the meantime I did almost the same change, this was the perfect solution!

Answer (score 4):

I was searching for the answer to this question in order to produce an array of results that could be easily json-encoded and sent as the response to an ajax call.  I wanted only the attributes of each object in the array of results.

Unfortunately, you can't just call to_json() on each result and then json-encode the entire thing; you end up with double-encoding.  Fortunately, though, the function and class posted by @willwashburn to solve this problem have now been included in php-activerecord, though they don't seem to have made it into the online documentation.

To return an array of results, do the following:

```
$data = MyModel::find('all');
foreach ($data as &$result) {
    $result = $result->to_array();
}
```

Your entire result set will now be an array of arrays, containing only the attributes of each object.  You can then do something like

```
echo(json_encode($data));
```

if you want to send it as the response to an ajax call.

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution:

```
$posts = Post::find('all');

$arrayResult = array_map(function($res){
  return $res->attributes();
}, $posts);
printf('<pre>%s</pre>', print_r($arrayResult, true));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyPHPActiveRecord extends PHPActiveRecord {

    public function toJSON() {
        return json_encode(get_object_vars($this));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
funciton ar2array($settings){
   $arr = array();
   foreach($settings as $fieldObj){
      $fieldName = $fieldObj->attributes["param"];
      $fieldValue = $fieldObj->attributes["value"];
      $arr[$fieldName] = $fieldValue;
   }
   return $arr;
}
$resultAsYouWant = ar2array($settings);
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

PS: If `->attributes` is private use its accesor method (there must be one) as `->getAttributes()` or equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

I found this looking for solution of the same problem that I encountered using Yii framework - there is simplier way to do this in Yii.

```
$posts = Posts::model()->findAll();

foreach($posts as $result)
{
    print_r($result->attributes);
}
```

It prints simple array as requested:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [title] => Title
    [text] => Text
)
```

Hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

1. Added the following method to the utils class found in lib\Utils.php

   ```
   public static function results_to_json($data)
   {
   $arr = array();
   if(count($data)>0){
       foreach($data as $row){
           array_push($arr, $row->to_array());
       }
   }
   return json_encode($arr);
   }
   ```
2. Call by:

   ```
   echo \ActiveRecord\Utils::results_to_json($dataobject);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously this is no longer relevant to the OP; however, considering that it still took me over an hour to find a solution for this (no thanks to php-activerecords docs), this may help someone else.

```
 $r = Model::find('$id')->attributes();
 $a = [];
 foreach ($r as $k => $v)
 {
     $a[$k] = $v;
 }
```

Perhaps not the most elegant, but works perfectly.